# Guaranteed method to match longest string in regular expression alternation

Tags: python, regex

For some reason I need to generate the regular expression from some arbitrary list by using alternations.

Let's say the user can input `"cat"`, `"dog"` and `"!@[]"`, it will generate `"cat|dog|!@\\{\\}"`.

The problem is that, can I make the re to match the longest term when several of the inputs contain common prefix?

For example:

`"god"`, `"godspeed"`, `"godzilla"` will generate `"god|godspeed|godzilla"`

I want it to match the longest term if there are several matches. That is to match `"godspeed"` rather than `"god"` if I use `re.finditer()` to match the string `"godspeeding"`

*I have tried in Python 3.7.1 and it seems it reports matches according to the order in the regular expression.* If this is always true, I can just sort the input (wrt length) before converting them to regular expression.

**However, I cannot find any documentation about this behavior and not sure if this will be unchanged in the future.**

Comment: Sort them by length in descending order. Also, if you need to match whole words use word boundaries, `\b(god|godspeed|godzilla)\b`. Combining these two things is usually sufficient.

Comment: This is how regular expressions work. It only consumes characters to make a match, it doesn't know anything about the *ideal* match per your specifications. Once a match is made, it's happy. Since it is endemic to the system itself, it doesn't surprise me if Python's documentation of its regexp implementation doesn't include notes about it.

Comment: @AdamSmith This is how *some* (well, I suppose 'most' at this point) regular expression engines works.. it is not a requirement that a regular expression engine is *greedy*. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines - "Note that many older, pre-POSIX engines were non-greedy and didn't have greedy quantifiers at all.". Also, there is no universal requirement that an alternation only evaluations one branch, or that it selects branch based on order: *this logic belongs to to a specific regular expression impl./contract*, in this specific case it's Python.

Comment: It seems like a legitimate question, and definitely shows prior research. I focused the title and drew out the stated/observed information to avoid re-information about the same.. programming is about *guarantees* (and a little bit of finger crossing when such is informal).

Comment: @user2864740 Yes this was my concern too because since the quantifiers are greedy, the alternations should be greedy too. But it seems that it all depends on the implementations. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

> As the target string is scanned, REs separated by '|' are tried from left to right. When one pattern completely matches, that branch is accepted.

This is specified behavior and will most likely not be changed in the future. You should be alright sorting wrt the lenghts and performing the regex match afterwards.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Would you explain the downvote? This seems to be a legitimate answer to me. If not pls explain what's wrong with it. Thanks ;-)

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I overlook this part and your solution definitely answers my question. PS. I did not downvote you :-p

Comment: Alright, glad I could help ;-)